# Integral of product between derivative and reciprocal of a function

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

What is the result of this integral?

$$
\int \frac{df(x)}{dx} \frac{1}{f(x)} dx
$$

How can I solve it analytically? I have tried to solve it by parts but I cannot find a solution.

Comment: what is $\frac{d}{dx} [\ln(u(x))]$?

Comment: I think you should rename your question with "reciprocal of a function."

Answer (score 2):

$\int \frac{df(x)}{dx} \frac{1}{f(x)} dx = \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx = \log|f(x) |+c$